# get Wall Facebook messages without Authentication

Tags: facebook, spring-mvc, spring-social

Do you know if there is any way to publish on my web app the facebook messages published by the users on my facebook wall application?

I'm using spring social and I tried to use the code you can see below:

```
facebook.feedOperations().getPosts()
```

With this sentence, it is launched an exception alerting that Authentication is needed.

Thanks.
Regard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. If you could, then Facebook would need to seriously evaluate their security. The user needs to give you permission to access their data. After authenticating can use the returned user token to access the user's Facebook wall posts.

Comment: But what I want it's not to publish user's wall post, it is to publish my facebook application posts which should be public to everybody.